# Exception while implementing navigator. Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: flutter

I started to play with flutter and trying to open a new screen after tapping on a button from main screen. I looked at similar questions asked before here and tried to follow the solutions provided, but am not quite sure how and where to implement the solution.

This is the exception I am getting :

```
Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
```

I think I know the root cause of this issue, ie, the context I am trying to refer doesn't have `Navigator` widget in it, but not sure how to resolve it. Below is my complete code :

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    Widget phoneSection = Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Welcome To City',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                ),
              ),
            )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget buttonSection = RaisedButton(
      child: const Text('Lets Take a Tour'),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      elevation: 4.0,
      splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2');
      },
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ATG',

      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Tour Guide'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[Image.asset(
            'images/bkm.png',
            width: 600.0,
            height: 240.0,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),

          phoneSection,
          buttonSection,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/screen2' : (BuildContext context) => new Screen2(),
      },
    );

  }

  void button1(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2');
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Screen 2"),

      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am looking for inputs as to where exactly I need to implement the `Navigator` widget reference with code snippet. Appreciate your help in this.

Comment: where do you call    -> button1  method?

Comment: @diegoveloper, initially I had placed the call here :onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2');
      }, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things you're doing wrong here. The first is that you have multiple `MaterialApp` instances. You should only ever have one of those.

The next issue is that in your `button1` method, you're using the widget's context to find a `Navigator`. But since the navigator is being built within that widget, it won't find it. This is essentially the context that you're using:

```
MyApp    <---- Context
  MaterialApp
    (Navigator)
      Scaffold 
        ...
```

And when you do Navigator.of(context) it starts at the current context and goes up the tree.

I'd advise splitting your app up so that you have a MyApp widget (or whatever you want to call it) ad then widgets for each screen. It's possible to do this without that by using a Builder widget, but it's a better practice to split up the build functions anyways.

This will do what you're wanting:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ATG',
      home: HomeScreen(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/screen2': (BuildContext context) => new Screen2(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    Widget phoneSection = Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Welcome To City',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    Widget buttonSection = RaisedButton(
      child: const Text('Lets Take a Tour'),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      elevation: 4.0,
      splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2');
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Tour Guide'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            'images/bkm.png',
            width: 600.0,
            height: 240.0,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          phoneSection,
          buttonSection,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void button1(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2');
  }
}

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Screen 2"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks @rmtmckenzie for the direction. I am going to try this out now.